# Not to show names which one of the entries has unwanted value

Tags: mysql

For example, there is such table "Eaten_food":

```
Name       Food
--------------------
Lisa       Grapes
Victoria   Broccoli
Oliver     Carrot
Lisa       Apple
Kayla      Pineapple
Oliver     Banana
Victoria   Kiwi
Kayla      Grapes
```

I want to do a query to show only names that didn't eat grapes.
So, for example, Kayla and Lisa ate grapes, so they shouldn't be on the result list.

```
SELECT Name FROM Eaten_food WHERE NOT Food = "Grapes" GROUP BY Name
```

This query doesn't work. What query should be correct in this case?

Comment: Do you have another table like `users` or `people` where `Name` is distinct/unique?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just created a random table for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Eaten_food
GROUP BY Name
HAVING BIT_OR(Food = "Grapes") = 0
```

There are many other ways to write the HAVING clause. Some of them are:

```
HAVING BIT_AND(Food <> "Grapes")
HAVING SUM(Food = "Grapes") = 0
HAVING MAX(Food = "Grapes") = 0
```

They all check that the value in `Food` column is never "Grapes" for the given group (`Name`).

The above conditions work for MySQL because a boolean condition returns either `0` or `1`. A standard SQL condition could be:

```
HAVING MAX(CASE Food WHEN 'Grapes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

and should work for any major RDBMS.

If you have table (like `people`) with distinct names, you can use a NOT EXISTS subquery condition:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM people p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Eaten_food f
  WHERE f.Name = p.Name
    AND f.Food = 'Grapes'
)
```

Depending on data this could be faster, because the `Eaten_food` doesn't need to be read entirely.

An equivalent query is:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN Eaten_food f
  ON  f.Name = p.Name
  AND f.Food = 'Grapes'
WHERE f.Name is NULL
```

All queries will benefit from a compsite index on `(Name, Food)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,food VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,food)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Lisa','Grapes'),
('Victoria','Broccoli'),
('Oliver','Carrot'),
('Lisa','Apple'),
('Kayla','Pineapple'),
('Oliver','Banana'),
('Victoria','Kiwi'),
('Kayla','Grapes');

SELECT DISTINCT x.name 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.food = 'grapes' 
          WHERE x.food <> 'grapes' 
            AND y.name IS NULL;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| Oliver   |
| Victoria |
+----------+
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ,

```
SELECT Name FROM Eaten_food WHERE NOT Food = "Grapes" and Name not in (select Name from Eaten_food where Food="Grapes") GROUP BY Name;
```